# How do I make a virtual machine with non-standard speed of time (timescale)?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, time, clock, clockspeed

I think it should be technically possible, but I don't know of any ways to do this in already existing software.

What I mean — the "hardware" clock in the VM should be able to run at different speeds, for example, several times slower than normal, or 100 times faster than normal. So, for example, a `Thread.sleep(1000);` call will not necessarily spend 1 second, but instead it could be any time, depending on the speed of the "hardware" clock. And as another example, if some game uses the timer to control speed of things' movements, then its speed will also change with the timer speed.

Also it would be interesting to know if the speed of actual hardware clock can be adjusted, and on which hardware.

#### Update

There are 2 seemingly similar questions, but they are about CPU speed, not timer speed (it's a totally different thing). So I think that this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate a slow machine in a VM?](http://superuser.com/questions/297550/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-machine-in-a-vm), also see [Slow development machine down?](http://superuser.com/questions/942804/slow-development-machine-down)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 they are about CPU speed, and I asked about **timer** speed.

Comment: True enough....

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's possible. I mean there is no obvious solution currently available, but I'm interested to see what answers this community comes up with.

Answer (score 7):

Virtual-box support exists on a config level [as explained on this official ticket](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5768#comment:6):

> Btw, this is
>
> `VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME "VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" 200`
>
> for double speed of the guest clock.
>
> GUI support currently not planned.

It does not make the time device to go faster.

Tested and works only for some aspects of every program, "perhaps" since it does not make the time device to go faster, and programs use it for part of their time synchronizations.

In other VM utilities:

Also, the opener of the above ticket mentioned:

> bochs and DOSbox can speed up or slow down VM by emulating CPU and/or timer slower or faster than normal.

Comment: +1, sounds interesting.
But not marking as accepted yet, since it's not complete solution (it does not make the time device to go faster).

Comment: Did you also try out the other alternate above-mentioned VM utilities for making the time device to go faster?

Comment: They are not general-purpose VMs, as I understand… but looks like for some use cases they are the solution

Answer (score 0):

Qemu may have a solution for you as well, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936920/increasing-the-speed-of-qemu-clock

Snippet:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -rtc base=localtime,clock=vm -icount shift=7,align=off,sleep=off ...
```